# trying to filter the data between two dates in codeigniter using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a form where i have two dates option **date from**
 and **date to** and when user clicks i am calling ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: $url,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $data,
    success: function (response)
    {
    if (response.status == 'OK') 
                {
                    var sales_summary = response.sales_summary;
                    $('#example1').find('tbody').empty();
                    $u = 1;
                    $.each(sales_summary, function() 
                    {
                        var new_row = '<tr>'+
                            '<td>' + $u + '</td>'+
                            '<td>' + this.name + '</td>'+
                            '<td>' + this.datetime + '</td>' +
                        '</tr>';
                        $u++;
                        $('#example1').find('tbody').append(new_row);
                        $('#loading_div').hide();
                    });

                }
    }`
```

php code in sql query where i am filtering the data by date:

```
if ($filter['date_from'] != '') {
       $this->db->where('transaction.created_on >=', strtotime($filter['date_from'])+3600);
    }
if ($filter['date_to'] != '') {
       $this->db->where('transaction.created_on <=', strtotime($filter['date_to'])+89999);
    }
```

**data type (Date)** = int(11)

**error** = SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1

**error position** = the above php code

Comment: I don't see the JSON here. What am I missing?

Comment: @BrianGottier  actually this error is not due to json or ajax, the query where i am trying to filter the data according to selected date is the reason.

Comment: Based on the code and information you've provided, I can't help you. That error looks like a JavaScript error, but you're showing us some PHP. I suggest trying to debug your code line by line. Reduce your code if necessary, so that you can determine the issue.

Comment: @BrianGottier i have edited the question for you to understand the code

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try BETWEEN

```
if ($filter['date_from'] != '' && $filter['date_to'] != '') {
   $this->db->where("transaction.created_on BETWEEN ".
   strtotime($date_from) + 3600 ." AND ".  strtotime($date_to) + 
   89999);
}
```

Comment: i think there must be problem in formatting of date, not in query